# cloning project from github but manage.py runserver doesn't work

Tags: python, django, git

So I tried cloning a project that I contribute to in Github. But, when I tried to run *python manage.py runserver*, it showed me the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\CLAIRE\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\CLAIRE\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 317, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Users\CLAIRE\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\CLAIRE\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\CLAIRE\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 106, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\CLAIRE\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'now'
```

Can someone please help me, please

Comment: please add more details to your question

Answer (score 3):

Install all the required packages in the requirements.txt:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt`
```

With the log, it seems that there is import issues with the front-end stuff. If the project is public, can you share it just to be more specific?